# Как вывести static переменную из функции?

Tags: php

```
<?php

function sta() {
  static $i = 0;
  $i++;
  return $i;
}
sta();
sta();
sta();
sta();
echo $i;
?>
```

Хочу чтобы переменная возвращала количество вызовов функции

Comment: про области видимости что-либо слышали?

Comment: слышали, слышали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется вы пытаетесь использовать инструмент не по назначению. Хотите иметь возможность получать доступ к подобному счетчику извне - используйте глобальную переменную или объекты

Например такой костыль с глобальной переменной:

```
function sta() {
    static $i = 0;
    if ($i == 0) {
        $GLOBALS['sta_i'] = &$i;
    }
    $i++;
    return $i;
}

sta();
sta();
sta();
sta();

echo $sta_i;
```

...или объектом:

```
class StaClass {
    private $i = 0;
    public function sta() {
        $this->i++;
        return $this->i;
    }
    public function getCount() {
        return $this->i;
    }
}

$o = new StaClass();
$o->sta();
$o->sta();
$o->sta();
$o->sta();

echo $o->getCount();
```

...еще вариант со ссылками, но без засорения глобальной области

```
function &sta() {
    static $i = 0;
    $i++;
    return $i;
}

$sta_i = &sta();
sta();
sta();
sta();

echo $sta_i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы возвращаете переменную `$i` в конце функции, достаточно просто ответ функции в переменную загонять и посмотреть, а так вы к ней не обратитесь напрямую.

```
<?php
function sta() {
  static $i = 0;
  $i++;
  return $i;
}
sta();
sta();
sta();
$count = sta();

echo $count; // Выведет 4
```

Но это тоже такой себе вариант.